# QuickBlox get Locations with GeoRect method

Tags: android, location, rectangles, quickblox

I'd like to get Locations inside of a rectangle. This is my code:

```
    public void getRadarUsers() {
```

double latitude1,longitude1,latitude2,longitude2;

```
    latitude1 = CommonProperties.map.getProjection().getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds.southwest.latitude;
    longitude1 = CommonProperties.map.getProjection().getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds.southwest.longitude;

    latitude2 = CommonProperties.map.getProjection().getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds.northeast.latitude;
    longitude2 = CommonProperties.map.getProjection().getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds.northeast.longitude;


    QBLocationRequestBuilder getLocationsBuilder = new QBLocationRequestBuilder();
    getLocationsBuilder.setPerPage(10); // only 10 locations
    getLocationsBuilder.setGeoRect(latitude1, longitude1, latitude2,
            longitude2);
    QBLocations.getLocations(getLocationsBuilder, new QBCallbackImpl() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(Result result) {
            if (result.isSuccess()) {
                QBLocationPagedResult locationsResult = (QBLocationPagedResult) result;
                if (locationsResult.getLocations() != null) {
                    for (QBLocation location : locationsResult
                            .getLocations()) {
                         UserVO user = new UserVO();
                         user.setLocation(location);
                         user.setUser(location.getUser());
                         QBCommon.getFileService().getUserFile(user);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Log for Request:
12-08 16:31:29.505: D/QBASDK RestRequest(29104): PARAMETERS
12-08 16:31:29.505: D/QBASDK RestRequest(29104):     per_page=10
12-08 16:31:29.505: D/QBASDK RestRequest(29104):     geo_rect=49.578363078876166;6.082663312554359;49.63331730521349;6.137594617903233
12-08 16:31:29.505: D/QBASDK RestRequest(29104): INLINE
12-08 16:31:29.505: D/QBASDK RestRequest(29104):     GET https://api.quickblox.com/geodata/find.json?per_page=10&geo_rect=49.578363078876166;6.082663312554359;49.63331730521349;6.137594617903233

Log for Response:
12-08 16:31:31.997: D/QBASDK RestResponse(29104): BODY
12-08 16:31:31.997: D/QBASDK RestResponse(29104):     '{"errors":{"geo_rect":["should be in GeoRect format"]}}'
12-08 16:31:32.005: D/QBASDK QBLocationPagedResult(29104): Request has been completed with error: [geo_rect should be in GeoRect format]

**As you can read the error is:
 geo_rect:should be in GeoRect format.**

The values for latitude and longitude are:

latitude1 = 49.578363078876166
longitud1 = 6.082663312554359

latitude2 = 49.63331730521349
longitud2 = 6.137594617903233

Any idea about the error please?

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATED:** I'm using Andoid SDK and QuickBlox version is 0.8.1
If I use QuickBlox version is 0.8. I don't get any error and I can get Locations.
it seems to be a bug. does anybody know how to report it?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out latest QuickBlox Android SDK 0.8.2 here http://quickblox.com/developers/Android#Download_Android_SDK 
This feature works without any problems